# Why is $5^{n+1}+2\cdot 3^n+1$ a multiple of $8$ for every natural number $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I have to show by induction that this function is a multiple of 8. I have tried everything but I can only show that is multiple of 4, some hints? The function is
$$5^{n+1}+2\cdot 3^n+1 \hspace{1cm}\forall n\ge 0$$, because it is a multiple of 8, you can say that$$5^{n+1}+2\cdot 3^n+1=8\cdot m \hspace{1cm}\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$$.

Comment: Please read the [How-to-ask page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, you should include the context of the question (why are you asking it?) and briefly what you've tried (where are you stuck?), otherwise it is not fit for Math SE. Since you've got an answer for this one already, please do this for subsequent questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: the difference between consecutive terms is:

$$
\require{cancel}
5^{n+2}+2\cdot 3^{n+1}+ \bcancel{1} - (5^{n+1}+2\cdot 3^n+\bcancel{1})
 = 5^{n+1}(5-1)+2\cdot 3^n(3-1) = 4 \cdot (5^{n+1}+3^n)
$$

The last factor is a sum of two odd numbers.

Comment: This was the easiest method and fun to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

If  $a_n=(2b+1)^n$

$$a_{m+2}-a_m=8(2b+1)^m\cdot\dfrac{b(b+1)}2$$ which is multiple of $8$ as $b(b+1)$ is even.

Comment: Your hint is to make a recurrence? I have to show it by only induction.

Comment: @LukasHaring, Is this not induction?

Comment: lab bhattacharjee has show you an elegant way to prove your claim. First check your result for $m=1,2 $ and then  proceed by induction using the recurrence given in this answer.

Comment: Yes, it's really cool but I have to understand how to get there by my own. :-)

Answer (score 2):

By induction:

It is true for case $n=1$, Let it be true for $n=k$ then

$5^{k+2} +2.3^{k+1} +1 = 5.5^{k+1}+3.2.3^k+1 = 2(5^{k+1} -1) + 3(5^{k+1}+2.3^k+1)$

The second part is a multiple of $8$ and one can easily  show that $(5^{k+1} -1)$ is a multiple of $4$.

Hint for showing  $(5^{k+1} -1)$ is a multiple of $4$:

$5^{k+2}-1 = 4.5^{k+1} + 5^{k+1} -1$

Comment: I think your hint makes it more difficult than necessary. Just observe that 5 = 1 mod 4, so 5^k = 1 mod 4 as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
**$\ds{\large n\ \mathsf{even}:}$**
\begin{align}
5^{n + 1} + 2 \times 3^{n} + 1 & =
5\pars{5^{n} - 1} + 2\pars{3^{n} - 1} + 8 =
5\pars{4\overbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}5^{k}}^{\ds{even}}}\ +\
4\ \overbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}3^{k}}^{\ds{even}} + 8
\end{align}

---

**$\ds{\large n\ \mathsf{odd}:}$**
\begin{align}
5^{n + 1} + 2 \times 3^{n} + 1 & =
\pars{5^{n + 1} - 1} + 6\pars{3^{n - 1} - 1} + 8
\\[5mm] & =
4\overbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}5^{k}}^{\ds{odd:\ 2p + 1}}\ +\
12\ \overbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2}3^{k}}^{\ds{odd:\ 2q + 1}} + 8
\qquad\qquad\pars{~p\ \mbox{and}\ q\ \mbox{are}\ integers~}
\\[5mm] & = 8p + 24q + 3 \times 8
\end{align}